# How do I make User fields required in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, frameworks

I'm trying to use the Default User Model in Django for a REST API but I don't know how to make fields like first_name, last_name, email required when people register. Would I have to use a custom User model or is this something that can be taken care of in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a custom user model. This will allow me to add more fields if I need to anyways. I found the following thread that helped me design my custom user model:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/BlxIeI6nHXo

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using HTML for your view. Then you can add the required attribute on an input tag. Further you can spice it up with css.

Take a look at:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: No, it's REST so I want it to send a status back if someone tries to POST without all of the information. Also, isn't it bad practice to have validation only on the frontend and not the backend as well?